# iPhone addObject to NSMutableArray from another ViewController Using IBAction

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I am trying to addObject to a NSMutableArray once the user taps the Add to Favorites button I can get the data into a NSDictionary, but when I pass the NSDictionary to the Array the NSLog comes back with nil.  Am I missing something?

```
-(IBAction) addtofavorites: (id)sender
{
    NSArray *key = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title", @"Description", nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:CurrentTitle, description.text, nil];
    NSDictionary *fadd = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:key];

    FavoritesViewController *fvc = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] init];
    [fvc.favorites addObject:fadd];
    [FavoritesViewController release];
}
```

Comment: So I went in a different direction but still have the same problem.  I am now saving my favorites using core data.  I am not sure how to add the game to my NSManagedObjectContex.  I have a Class called Games and want to pass 3 NSString.  Do I create a method in my appDelegate, Games or in my Context in my ViewController?  Sure does take a while to teach yourself Core Data, but I think I got a good handle on it now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
FavoritesViewController *fvc = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] init];
[fvc.favorites addObject:fadd];
[FavoritesViewController release];
```

doesn't look right. You should already have a FavoritesViewController initialized (in which can just access it and call -addObject:)...

**EDIT**

First, how does the current view controller (the one that has -addtofavorites: defined on it) relate to FavoritesViewController? How would the user navigate between these two view controllers?

Second, would the list of favorites persist across different runs of the app? If so, how do you plan to save/restore favorites?

Third, rather than add favorites to a view controller, you would probably do better to add them to an underlying 'model' that would be used to populate the FavoritesViewController.

Separating the 'model' from the 'view' can be very powerful, while also simplifying your code.

Comment: I create the IBAction in my DetailViewController the is why I alloc and init it in the IBAction

Comment: But you alloc, init and release fvc in rapid succession. Why?

Comment: Because I thought the fvc.favorites should have the my NSDictionary object. So I am done with my FavoritesViewController

Comment: Well, yes and no. You may be done with your FavoritesViewController for the purposes of adding an object but by releasing it, you are essentially deleting it. I will elaborate in edit to my original answer.

Comment: The User navigates between the two view controllers using a TabbarController

Comment: I am still working on how to save the favorites file, I was thinking of using a plist and saving it to my documents folder in the Sandbox, but I am not quite sure how to do that yet.   I like the idea of using a Model for controlling my data for favorites, but I have also be wonder how to make sure that I only add it once.

Comment: If you are using a UITabBarController, then you will need to add an instance of FavoritesViewController to its viewControllers list. I am surprised that you are not doing this in IB and binding an instance variable to that FavoritesViewController. This would mean that you didn't need to worry about creating FavoritesViewController programmatically.

Comment: I would focus on implementing the favorites model first and then worry about saving/restoring it. There are many ways to go, but ultimately you will want you -addToFavorites: method to check the favorite-to-be-added does not already exist in list of favorites. I don't know enough about the objects that are being viewed and tagged as favorites. It might be that they deserve their own class and that you put in place checks that insure that each instance is unique. Having done this, you could compare pointers for uniqueness - and maybe just use NSMutableSet to manage lists of these objects.

Comment: Alright I have been thinking about this, all my data is coming from a plist already.  Would it be easier to add a BOOL to the plist the could be turned off and on.  I would set all of the to off at first, but as the user turns them on they would be saved to my documents folder in the sandbox using a plist.  Does that make sense?  My question is how would i notify the addtofavorites button to be notified when the user deletes it from the favorites list?

Comment: So, your objects would each have a boolean flag to indicate whether or not they are favorites? That sounds reasonable. As for noticing that addtofavorites button being notified about changes in favorite-ness, are you providing single-selection and are you enabling/disabling addtofavorites button according to selected object's favorite-ness? If so, you could use notifications - and have notification of change in favorite-ness (or addition/deletion of object) cause update of addtofavorites button.

Comment: I am in the process right now, I created a FavoritesModalController were I create a NSMutableArray containing a collection of NSDictionary.   This way I can give my Dictionary from my addtofavorties button and it will be add and save at the same time. Not really sure what type of method to use to do this? Before I save the file I was going to check to see if the NSArray in my FavoritesViewController has that current title. I have been thinking about how to do this but not sure how to put the code together?  Thanks, BIG D

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is in your header file create an instance variable for your FavoritesViewController that you retain. Then use lazy init when the addtofavorites is pressed. Something like below

```
 if (!detailViewController) 
  {
    self.fvc = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] init];
  }

 [self.fvc.favorites addObject:fad];
```

Then just release the FavoritesViewController object in dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [fvc release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```